# using the codename one calendar lib

Tags: codenameone

Good day all, I was recently searching through the codename one external lib page and I saw the calendar lib, which really interests me because it will make my current project and future ones less stressful, the problem is that on opening the page I saw no downloadable codename one lib, neither did I see a way to go about using it. A lil help will be appreciated on how to get the lib up and running in my current project. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you searched the extensions library for **Calendar**, you should see a download button on the bottom-right corner.

Download it -> right-click on your project -> Codename One -> Refresh-cn1lib files, and you can start using it.

```
myButton.addActionListener(evt -> {
    DeviceCalendar calendar = DeviceCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.saveEvent(calendarID, eventID, title, startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp, allDayEvent, notes, location, reminders);
});
```

Comment: Any example on how to use it?

Comment: @rockspetre if the answer is helpful you should upvote and accept the answer by checking the checkbox next to it to give Diamond (and yourself) additional points which are pretty helpful in this site

Comment: On trying the lib out....I received an error telling me that I require android.permission.Device calendar